# making a Java application synchronize the contacts on the PC, when an android phone is connected to it

Tags: java, android, usb, interfacing

I do not know how to start building upon this simple idea :

When an android phone is connected to a PC, a Java application running on the PC detects the device and starts synchronizing the contacts in the android phone.

Can anyone help me how do I start this ? I know how to write applications in Java but have never worked with android OS or have made application for the android operating system. That is the reason I am unable to start this.Please tell,if there is anything I need to delve in before I should start.

Comment: a) learn [how to](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) write Android apps b) think about how the PC and the device should talk to each other. You can't use USB to simply communicate with each other.

Comment: @zapl a) that is what i want to know.Android app for PC (on ubuntu)? !

Answer (score 1):

The contacts info can only be got in the android apps, so you have to write an android app and a pc app, and transfer data between them.

1. When a device is connected to pc, start your pc app automatically.
2. Install your android app to the device.

   `adb install apk-path`
3. Start the android app.

   `adb shell am start -n pkgname/activityname`
4. Start a tcp connecton.

   `adb forward tcp:port tcp:port`

   read this [page](http://www.anothem.net/archives/2010/10/15/android-usb-connection-to-pc/) for details.
5. Try to collect contacts in android app and transfer them to pc. There are many articles about how to get contacts in android, and the data transmission will use Serialization and Socket programming.

adb (android debug tool) is a android sdk tool, you need to learn more about it.